# Where are uploaded files to drive by googleapis? Nodejs-Express

Tags: node.js, express, drive, google-apis-explorer

I made a project that uses `googleapis.google.auth.JWT` for authentication and `googleapis.google.drive`, But when I upload files, I don't find them on my Drive. So, does that process make something like a new empty Drive account or what? And how can I see them on Drive?